# Change color and background of chunk ouput in Quarto document

Tags: html, css, r, quarto

I have seen how to customize chunks appearance in Quarto documentation (https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html#appearance), but how to customize color and/or background of chunks *output* so that it is distinguishable from plain text beyond its font style in the rendered HTML document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quarto code chunk output is wrapped within a Div with class `cell-output`. If you want to style specific chunk output, use `classes` chunk option to assign a class and add/modify css styles for `cell-output` within that `<classes>` class.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
css: style.css
---

```{r}
#| classes: styled-output
print("This is some output")
```
````

**style.css**

```css
.styled-output .cell-output {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

---

[image: chunk output styled using css]

And if you want to style all the chunk output identically, then simply modify the `cell-output` class.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
css: style.css
---

```{r}
print("This is some output")
```

```{r}
print("More code chunk")
```
````

**style.css**

```css
.cell-output {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

---

[image: all chunk output styled with css]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually had some css code in a `{=html}` chunk right below the YAML, so i used your `.cell-output{}` code in it and it worked!

Comment: Any idea how to get a border around the output box? I tried `border-color: black;` and `border-width: 1px;` but had no effect.

Comment: @retodomax, try with the following, `.cell-output pre { border: black 1px solid; }`.